# Displaying the complete dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe in Google Colab that displays a Query ID, a Brand ID and the Brand Name. It's a pretty hefty amount of lines (193k lines approx.) and I think that that amount of lines is responsible for the following:

[image]

The code I'm using is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_fwf("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/100/docs.txt", header=None, names=["Query ID", "Brand ID", "Brand Name"]))
df
```

I wanted all the lines in the dataframe to be displayed. Is it possible to display all the values in the lines instead of this shortened version and, if so, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`.